# Python. Multiprocessing pool. How to obtain all results

Tags: python

Started to play with Python and stuck with one silly situation.
My function returns two values. Using MP I'd like to make execution faster.

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(bar, baz):
    print("start")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("end")
    return bar, baz


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)

    ret = []
    i = 0
    while i < 4 :
        j = i + 1
        while j < 4 :
            results = [pool.apply_async(foo, args=(i, j))]
            j = j + 1
        i = i + 1

    output = [p.get() for p in results]
    print(output)
```

In the same time finally I want to get a list of returned values like [(0,1),(0,2),...]. However I see only one pair instead. Any idea how to change this code shortly to have all results and do not lost parallelism?
Thanks!

```
start
start
start
start
end
start
end
start
end
end
end
end
[(2, 3)]
```

Comment: The only output you printed is the last one, the value of `results` on exit from the loop.  Were you trying to make `results` a list of tuples?

Answer (score 5):

You're overwriting your `results` list on each iteration, but you should be appending to it.  This should do the trick:

```
results = []
while i < 4 :
    j = i + 1
    while j < 4 :
        results.append(pool.apply_async(foo, args=(i, j)))
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1

output = [p.get() for p in results]
```

Answer (score 5):

**DIAGNOSIS**

Here's your code with a little debugging, and using `for` statements for readability:

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(i+1, 4):
        results = [pool.apply_async(foo, args=(i, j))]
        print("TRACE", results]

output = [p.get() for p in results]
print("FINAL", output)
```

Looking at the output, you can see the problem: although you made 6 distinct result collectors, `result` is merely the most recent at any given time.  Thus, you need to collect them all.

Output:

```
TRACE [<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7faf4b711390>]
TRACE [<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7faf4b7114e0>]
TRACE [<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7faf4b711588>]
TRACE [<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7faf4b711630>]
TRACE [<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7faf4b7116d8>]
start
TRACE [<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7faf4b711780>]
start
start
start
end
end
start
start
end
end
end
end
FINAL [(2, 3)]
```

---

**SOLUTION**

"Merely" use a nested-loop list comprehension to get the list of result applications you want:

```
results = [pool.apply_async(foo, args=(i, j))
              for i in range(4)
                 for j in range(i+1, 4)
          ]
print("TRACE", results)

output = [p.get() for p in results]
print("FINAL", output)
```

Output:

```
TRACE [<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7f52af945390>, 
       <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7f52af945438>, 
       <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7f52af9454e0>, 
       <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7f52af945588>,  
       <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7f52af945630>, 
       <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7f52af9456d8>]
start
start
start
start
end
end
end
end
start
start
end
end
FINAL [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: What is the rationale of using multiprocessing inside of a (nested) for loop?

Comment: If  you want OP's real-life answer, you should post your comment to the question, rather than this solution.
One common reason, as in this case, is that "foo" is a relatively slow, non-blocking function.  Thus, making asynchronous calls will allow multiple threads to receive useful cycles in parallel.